# Google Maps API v2: How to make marker tooltip clickable?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

When I click a marker on the map activity it will appear a tooltip that contains the title and the snippet of the marker. Can I add an onClick actions to this tooltip programmatically?

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
        .title("Title")
        .snippet("Snippet");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It called [Info Window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) and you can add the click event like this

```
 mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: But if I have two or more markers, do i have to write another Override in the same InfoWindowClickListener or do I have to re-write another InfoWindowClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

The second question was asked 2.5 years ago, but it still hasn't been answered, so yes - there is a way to cover different tooltip click events for different markers.

Kotlin code:

Firstly add the click listener for the info window:

```
googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MarkerClick())
```

Secondly implement the marker click:

```
internal class MarkerClick : GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
  override fun onInfoWindowClick(marker: Marker) {
    println(marker.title)
  }
}
```

I haven't implemented this in Java, although the listener class should look very similar:

```
class MarkerClick implements GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        System.out.println(marker.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Println is obviously only the example of what you can do.

It's wider described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows#info_window_events

Comment: You can as well use marker tags to store some specific data for the marker, like it's uuid or anything. This way you can for example navigate to another part of your app, depending on the tag.